# Unwanted date diminution

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, cookies, kendo-ui

Following code example provided by Telerik I am trying to preserve Kendo Grid state. Everything seems to be working but whenever I use date column filter and reload page the date in filter is decreased by one day... I pick 5th Oct., refresh and BAM! filter says 4th Oct. :) Any clues?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#ProjectsGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var state = JSON.parse($.cookie("projectsState"));
    if (state) {
        if (state.filter) {
            parseFilterDates(state.filter,  grid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields);
        }
        grid.dataSource.query(state);
    }
    else {
        grid.dataSource.read();
    }
});

function dataBound(e) {
    var grid = this;
    var dataSource = this.dataSource;

    var state = kendo.stringify({
        page: dataSource.page(),
        pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
        sort: dataSource.sort(),
        group: dataSource.group(),
        filter: dataSource.filter()
    });

    $.cookie("projectsState", state);
    if ($.cookie('empRows')) {
        $.each(JSON.parse($.cookie('empRows')), function() {                        
            var item = dataSource.get(this);
            var row = grid.tbody.find('[data-uid=' + item.uid + ']');
            row.addClass('k-state-selected');
        })
    }
}


function parseFilterDates(filter, fields) {
    if (filter.filters) {
        for (var i = 0; i < filter.filters.length; i++) {
            parseFilterDates(filter.filters[i], fields);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (fields[filter.field].type == "date") {
            filter.value = kendo.parseDate(filter.value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not the complete example. Try posting it in JSFiddle or JSBin so we can debug it and find for the solution. Otherwise it is pretty hard to say.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kendo DatePicker Max date issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056544/kendo-datepicker-max-date-issue)

Comment: I see no connection between questions what so ever... Can you elaborate?